# Poisson process and expected value in combination of waiting time

Tags: probability, poisson-process

In a store, a cashier only helps people when 5 people are in the queue. The people arrive at the cash desk according to a poisson process with a rate of 1 people per 2 minutes. What is the expected time that the cashier helps a customer?

I thought, you just do 5 x 2 = 10 minutes as expected value to have 5 people at the cash desk. But you could also see it als independent variables which are exponentially distributed. Can someone explain me which method I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought, you just do 5 x 2 = 10 minutes as expected value to have 5 people at the cash desk. But you could also see it als independent variables which are exponentially distributed. Can someone explain me which method I need to use?

People arrive at an average rate of one per two minutes, so the expected time to arrival of the fifth customer is indeed ten minutes.   This is *because* the interarrival times are iid exponential random variables.

The Law of Total Expectation says the expected time to the fifth arrival equals the sum of the expected inter arrival times. $$\mathsf E(T_5)=\mathsf E(T_1)+\mathsf E(T_2{-}T_1)+\mathsf E(T_3{-}T_2)+\mathsf E(T_4{-}T_3)+\mathsf E(T_5{-}T_4)$$

Now, the memoryless property of the Poisson Process entails that each of those interarrival times is an independent and identically exponentially distributed random variable. $$\mathsf E(T_5)=5\mathsf E(T_1)$$

And we know that the expected time to the first arrival is two minutes.$$\mathsf E(T_5)=10$$